# Java - Calculator without operators not working without showing any errors

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a calculator without any operators that relate to the opration itself I try to solve (comparison operators and loops with operators are fine).
problem is, Eclipse is showing this in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Calculator.addOne(Calculator.java:22)
at Calculator.add(Calculator.java:78)
at Program.main(Program.java:8)
```

And this is my code - Calculator class: http://pastebin.com/jLGe6atB

And my main() method:

```
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calculator1 = new Calculator(8135, 6);
    calculator1.add();
}
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem? (Please don't ask why am I doing this, it's just for fun)

Thanks and sorry for your time.

REQUEST: "post add() and addOne() here please:

```
        public int addOne(int DigitArray)
    {
            String stringNum1 = Integer.toString(DigitArray);
            String[] arrNum1 = stringNum1.split("");
            int[] newArrNum1 = new int[arrNum1.length];
               for (int i = 0; i < arrNum1.length; i++) {
                  newArrNum1[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrNum1[i]);
               }
            int lastDigit = newArrNum1[newArrNum1.length-1];
            switch(lastDigit)
            {
            case 0:
                    lastDigit = 1;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 1:
                    lastDigit = 2;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 2:
                    lastDigit = 3;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 3:
                    lastDigit = 4;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 4:
                    lastDigit = 5;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 5:
                    lastDigit = 6;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 6:
                    lastDigit = 7;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 7:
                    lastDigit = 8;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 8:
                    lastDigit = 9;
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            case 9:
                    lastDigit = 0;
                    updateNumberPlus(lastDigit, arrNum1, newArrNum1);
                    System.out.println(lastDigit);
                    return lastDigit;
            default:
                    return lastDigit;
            }
    }
    public int add()
    {
            int i = 0;
            while(i <= num2)
            {
                    i++;
                    this.addOne(num1);
                    if(i == num2)
                    {
                            result = 0;
                            System.out.print(result);
                            return result;
                    }
            }
            return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do a `String.split("")` you will get an empty `String` element as the first and last elements of your `Array`.

You then iterate over the array, calling `Integer.parseInt()` on each element, which fails on the empty string elements.

A simple hack would be to change your `for` loop to look like;

```
for(int i = 1; i < arrNum1.length - 1; i++) {
```

It's a little ugly though :P

Comment: No problem. You might consider `polling` each character in the string, using `String.charAt(0)`, and then `String.substring(1)`, that to me seems like a slightly cleaner approach.